# Pandas get first and last value of column from group

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

Hi I have `dataframe` that contains multiple rows for the same ID. One of the columns is a Date (in ascending order). I want to calculate the date difference between the first entry and last.

I am doing this by instantiating a pandas constructor as follows:

```
g = df.groupby('ID')

print(pd.DataFrame({'first':g.Date.nth(0), 'last':g.Date.nth(-1)}))
```

The first value is correct, however, the last value is nowhere near correct.

For example, for a specific id, the `first date` is `2000-05-08` and the `last date` is `8/21/2010`. The result outputted is:

```
               first       last
ID                         
31965.0        2000-05-08  2002-12-29
```

`2002-12-29` is somewhere in the middle.

Sample Data:

```
ID  Date
31965   5/8/2000
31965   5/10/2000
31965   5/18/2000
31965   5/22/2000
31965   5/23/2000
31965   5/25/2000
31965   5/30/2000
31965   6/7/2000
31965   6/8/2000
31965   6/11/2000
31965   6/13/2000
.....
31965   4/11/2009
31965   5/9/2009
31965   5/16/2009
31965   5/23/2009
31965   2/5/2010
31965   2/26/2010
31965   3/13/2010
31965   4/10/2010
31965   8/21/2010
```

I want my result for ID 31965 to be: 5/8/2000 and 8/21/2010 so that I can eventually work out the date difference.

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset showing error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks for your comment. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this in one step, be sure your 'Date' column is dtype datetime,

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df.groupby('ID')['Date'].agg(['first','last'])
```

Now, I suspect maybe your data isn't order correctly, but if you still wanted to earliest and the latest date then you can do this:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Date'].agg(['min','max']).rename(columns={'min':'first','max':'last'})
```

Or you can use sort_values then:

```
df.sort_values('Date').groupby('ID')['Date'].agg(['first','last'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After sorting the last date seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You probably might have to parse the last date in this way:

```
import datetime

def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime(str(x), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Here, you feed your date string into the function, and the function returns a parsed date. You can parse the first date similarly, and produce something consistent with the last date; the only thing you might need to change in the region `%m/%d/%Y`. That should solve your problem. Read this page for more information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why should I parse the date though? Aren't they in the same format?

Comment: Parsing the dates with datetime will let you find out the difference as well. I am not saying you absolutely have to use datetime, I am just saying parsing all your dates using this library keeps things consistent, and you can easily find out the difference between the dates just by subtracting one from the other.

Comment: Yes, that is true I completely agree. My problem was with obtaining the last date for comparison.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the problem in a different way and didn't answer your main question. To find the first and last dates, you could use the min and max of a (sorted or unsorted) list of parsed dates to get your dates.

Comment: No worries my friend! Thank you for your time. Yes, I managed to get my desired output.